# Framework with multiple targets and shared sources

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, swiftpm

I have a framework with two targets (`A` and `B`) with the following file structure:

```
FooFramework
|__ A
     |__ Foo.swift
     |__ Bar.swift
     |__ Foobar.swift
|__ B
     |__ Barfoo.swift
```

`B` basically has a subset of `A`'s sources (where `B` is set as a target), e.g. `B` only uses `Foo.swift` and `Bar.swift`, but not `Foobar.swift`.

Now I have an app that needs both framework `A` and `B` (in separate targets targets).

At this point I'm unsure how to setup the `Package.swift` file for this setup to work. Whenever I open the `Package.swift` in `Xcode` and try to build framework `B`, the compiler is complaining about missing types in `Barfoo.swift`, because they are included in `Bar.swift`.

This is how I've setup the `Package.swift` file:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Framework",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11),
        .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "A",
            targets: ["A"]),
        .library(
            name: "B",
            targets: ["B"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "Dependency", url: "https://github.com/...", .exact("1.0.0"))
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "A",
            dependencies: [
                "Dependency",
            ],
            path: "A",
            exclude: [
                "Info.plist",
            ],
            resources: [
                .process("fonts"),
            ]
        ),
        .target(
            name: "B",
            dependencies: ["A"],
            path: "B",
            exclude: [
                "Info.plist",
            ],
            resources: [
                .process("../A/fonts"),
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ATests",
            dependencies: ["A"],
            path: "ATests",
            exclude: [
                "Info.plist"
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

Related sources, but unfortunately unhelpful:

- [How to resolve Swift Package Manager target overlapping sources error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067701/how-to-resolve-swift-package-manager-target-overlapping-sources-error)
- https://forums.swift.org/t/two-libraries-with-shared-source-overlapping-error/32448

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @SamDoggett Unfortunately, not. We build the other targets as XCFrameworks and manually add them to the app.